# Ubuntu version for ATI Radeon 9200 video card

Tags: drivers, system-installation, 13.04, amd-graphics, radeon

What is the highest version of Ubuntu that I can install in my Pentium 4 laptop with an ATI Mobility Radeon 9200 video card?

I tried installing 13.04 but I couldn't start the GUI. I read that there are compatibility problems since the drivers are not available in the latest releases. I currently have Ubuntu 9.04 installed and it works fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04 has a PAE kernel. Maybe your CPU does't support PAE (physical address extension). Then try Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (Long Term Support), it's supported until April 2017.

If you want maximize your computer install ATI driver, follow this guide:

1. Open terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type these commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases fakeroot libqtgui4
   sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
   sudo amdconfig --initial -f
   ```
3. Restart your computer